# How do I run my iPhone app on the iPad simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode

I recently updated to the new version of xcode.  Big big mistake I have been have constant problems ever since.

How do I run my iPhone app in the iPad simulator.  The option to do so has disappeared!

I used to have the option when building to run either on iPhone or iPad device or simulator.  Now I can only choose simulator or device and there is no option for ipad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the device type from the Hardware menu in the simulator.

Comment: When I change the device in the menu it simply closes the app and opens the iPad simulator with no App.  Then when I Build and Run again it just opens the iPhone simulator again

Comment: That is because you kill the debugger session when you change device type. Either relaunch the app from the simulator, or change the project configuration.
The reason that you had two version before was probably that you had the iPhone-only 3.1.3 SDK + the iPad-only 3.2 SDK. Now with the 4 SDK, you have three device types (iPhone, iPad, iPhone4) -- all in one SDK